# Steganography in android with native Java library support issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random, steganography

I am developing a multi-platform application which will use the "F5 Steganography" to hide a message inside a JPG image captured from the device's camera.
Currently my objectives are to make an android application and desktop Java application.
I have found the jar file of "F5 Steganography" from [here](https://code.google.com/p/f5-steganography/) 
I have successfully implemented the library in Java desktop application but the problem is coming in android implementation.
I have imported the jar file in the android project but in the embedding and extraction of the message, I am facing issues on android.

- **Extract issue**

On Extract, the issue I am facing now is that the imported library is using "sun.security.provider.SecureRandom" but android is unable to find it.
here is log-cat error:

```
10-06 22:25:44.324: E/dalvikvm(32150): Could not find class 'sun.security.provider.SecureRandom', referenced from method crypt.F5Random.<init>
```

Now I am guessing that android is not supporting the "sun.security.provider.SecureRandom" library, if it is so, the what should I do? Can I import the library manually? P.S I don't want to change anything in "F5 Steganography" library code due to the fact it is being used as it is on Java platform. Here is the code for reference:

```
public void clk1(View v){
    EditText eto=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText ett=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Extract e=new Extract();
    String information[] = new String[5];
    information[0]="-p";
    information[1]="123";
    information[2]="-e";
    information[3]=ett.getText().toString();
    information[4]=eto.getText().toString();
    e.main(information);
}
```

- **Embed Issue**

On Embed, I am facing an issue similar to before. Error is saying that it could not find the "james.JpegEncoder" class in the library, yet it is present there as seen in the [attached image](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/166/acud.jpg).

Here is log-cat trace:

```
10-06 23:00:39.678: E/dalvikvm(410): Could not find class 'james.JpegEncoder', referenced from method main.Embed.main
```

Here is the code for reference:

```
public void clk0(View v){
    EditText eto=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText ett=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText eti=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Embed e=new Embed();
    String information[] = new String[8];
    information[0]="-e";
    information[1]=ett.getText().toString();
    information[2]="-p";
    information[3]="123";
    information[4]="-q";
    information[5]="100";
    information[6]=eti.getText().toString();
    information[7]=eto.getText().toString();
    e.main(information);
}
```

What should I do to counter this problem? I have reached here after solving many issues but got stuck here. I have searched through the Internet and could not find a proper solution even remotely relating to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use in Android the tool you referred (https://code.google.com/p/f5-steganography), you have to import some libraries from sun or include in your project the following classes from sun.security.provider:

- [NativePRNG.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java)
- [NativeSeedGenerator.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/NativeSeedGenerator.java)
- [SecureRandom.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java)
- [SeedGenerator.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/SeedGenerator.java)
- [SunEntries.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/SunEntries.java)

This post is a bit old but might help others in the futre... I just tried myself and works like charm :)